# A connected locally compact metric space is sigma-compact without AC

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

Is it possible to prove that a connected locally compact metric space is sigma-compact without using the Axiome of Choice?

Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you indicate how the usual(?) proof uses AC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The proof I know use the fact that a paracompact and connected locally-compact space is sigma-compact. However it is hard to show that a metric space is paracompact and it uses the axiom of choice so I'm looking for a more straightforward argument.

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086756/is-locally-compact-connected-metric-space-sigma-compact)